# type casting of byte and int

Tags: java

I'd a code snippet:

```
class AutoTypeCast{
    public static void main(String...args){
        int x=10;
        byte b=20;//no compilation error
        byte c=x;//compilation error
    }
}
```

Why `20` is automatically type-casted to `byte` while `x` not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I have to cast 0 to byte when the method argument is byte?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324372/why-do-i-have-to-cast-0-to-byte-when-the-method-argument-is-byte)

Comment: Many more similar/duplicate questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935699/java-implicit-conversion-of-int-to-byte, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369493/integer-to-byte-casting-in-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81392/java-why-do-i-receive-the-error-message-type-mismatch-cannot-convert-int-to-b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `x` is an `int` and has a wider range as `byte`. That is why there may be data loss is you assign it to `byte`.

`20` is a constant and while compile time garanteed to be in the range of `byte`.

Answer (score 3):

Because compiler is not able to figure out the value of X at compile time. So it assume that X can contain value which is greater than byte range. If you make variable X as final then it will not give you compile time error.

```
        final int x=10;
        byte b=20;//no compilation error
        byte c=x;//no compilation error
```

Answer (score 1):

20 always can be represented by a byte, while x, which according to the compiler can be any integer, may be too large to be represented by a byte.

Answer (score 1):

`20` is in `-128..127` range, so it's value fits into `byte`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case `x` is initialized to 10, so there will be no data loss in the conversion from a 32-bit `int` to an 8-bit `byte`. But in general, when converting from `int` to `byte`, there can be data loss, so the rules of the Java language forbid assigning `int` values to a `byte` without a cast. This rule is designed to make it more difficult to write buggy code. By inserting the `(byte)` cast, you are effectively telling the compiler: "Yes, I have thought about the possibility of data loss, and it is not a problem here (or, that's actually what I want)."

Answer (score 1):

When the compiler looks at the line

```
byte b=20;
```

it knows it's looking for a byte after *b=*.  When it finds a constant numeric value it knows at compile time that it will definitely be in the range of **byte** so it will automatically cast it.

When is sees the line

```
byte c=x;
```

it's once again looking for a byte after *c=* but instead of finding a numeric constant, finds a variable that already has a defined type and, at compile time, can't be sure that it will be in the range of **byte** so you get an error.

Answer (score 0):

X defined as integer, while narrowing there may be data loss, that is why compiler error. Refer [jvm spec for conversions & promotions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html)

Answer (score 0):

Up-casting is automatic where as down-casting or narrowing (`byte c=x;`) should be explicit as it might cause loss of precision which a programmer should be aware of explicitly. To correct it you need to put an explicit cast `byte c=(byte)x;`